# CSS3 colour opacity whilst naming the colour through keyword, not rgba()

Tags: css, colors, opacity, alpha, rgba

I enjoy using the *Extended Colour Keywords* from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color, but I'd like to be able to specify the  `opacity`/alpha-channel for my `color`/`border-color`/`background-color`, all without having to resort to the decimal or hexadecimal colour specs themselves (e.g., still referring to the primary colour by its name/keyword).

Is there an alternative to [`rgba()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-def) that lets you specify the desired opacity of a keyword-based colour?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @LGSon, but you can use `opacity: alpha` its css3 syntax, but it will cause the content to have inherit the opacity as well.